# Number of users who edit a question and CW questions

Tags: support, editing, community-wiki

I am used to the fact that when 5 different users edit a question, that is automatically changed to a CW question.

Is this still valid? Does the number of editors include also the OP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741), the automatic triggers for CW conversion include:

> - The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.
> - The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.
> - The question generates more than 30 answers.

Also,

> Rollbacks do not reverse any of the Community Wiki mode calculations.

(I don't know for sure that these numbers are valid for us on EL&U or still current.)

Comment: I was wondering if after the blog article about the meaning of CW questions, something could have changed.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, the question ‘[What is “context specific”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/62085/revisions)’ has exactly five edits by five different users, none by the original poster. It has apparently not changed to a CW question. I think this directly contradicts the documentation in the Meta.SO post [cited by aedia λ](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1819/14073).

Comment: One of the editors just changed the tags, which is not considered an edit, for the purposes of changing the post in CW. The body of the post must be edited by at least five different users. It is all to see if the author of the post is counted, but I guess it is not, as he created the post, not edited it.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Too bad I cannot downvote my own answer …

Comment: Well, it could be the initial edit is considered, but the post has not been made CW because the cron task which does that didn't still run. (I am making a supposition.)